# SonarQube Doesn't Display the Coverage

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, junit4

I have a Java Maven project and I wrote unit tests using Junit. When I run Tests with coverage, IDE shows the percentage of coverage. But after integrate the project with SonarQube, it only shows the number of unit test cases and shows coverage as 0% in the sonarQube.

Below is a screenshot of SonarQube.

[image: Sonar Report]

Since I need to integrate the project with SonarQube, I added jacoco-maven plugin and maven-surefire plugin to the pom file. Below is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="....">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>.....</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>coverage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>

                            <execution>
                                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>

                            <execution>
                                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` , It generates below files.

[image: generated folders]

Inside of surefire-reports there are xml files for each test class. But in SonarQube it shows only the number of unit test cases and shows coverage as 0%.

Can you help me to get the coverage on SonarQube?

Comment: Your settings looks quite different to these found on the net: https://www.baeldung.com/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage

Comment: @Mar-Z I tried as that blog but it didn't solved the issue. But I found the solution. I needed to add some more plugins. I will add my solution as an answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.I added below properties to the `<properties>` section in pom file.

```
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
```

Then added below profile to the pom file.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>coverage</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                            <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

This generated jacoco-ut.exec and jacoco.xml. Then run `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` in the terminal. This solved my issue.